# apply jquery on html loaded from load function

Tags: jquery

How to pass the returned value (data.url) from ajax post to the element in the new html loaded via ajax ?

```
 $("#askques").on("submit", function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();               
             $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'post.php',
             data: $(this).serialize(),       
             dataType: 'json',
             error : function(){ alert("error");},
             success : function(data){ alert(data.url); },
             complete : function(){ $( "#askcon" ).load( "form.htm", function() {});} 
       });
    });
```

Form.html:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="0" class="">

<tr>
<td>
<p id="res"></p>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

which is in the new loaded html should show the data.url value of ajax post data ?

Comment: In which tag do you want it exactly? p?

Comment: yes, <p id="res"></p>

Comment: `$('#askcon #res').html( data.url )`?

Comment: do `$("p #res").text(data.url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to wait for both the ajax and the `load` to complete, like this

```
$("#askques").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type     : 'POST',
        url      : 'post.php',
        data     : $(this).serialize(),
        dataType : 'json'
    }).always(function(data) {
        if ('url' in data) {
            $("#askcon").load("form.htm", function () {
                $('#res').html(data.url);
            });
        }
    });
});
```